# How many two digit numbers are there such that when multiplied by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 don't change their sum of digits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example $18$ has a sum of digits equal to $1+8=9$, and when multiplied by any of those given numbers the resulting numbers sum of digits is still $9$.

I've realised that every number which has the sum of its digits equal to $9$ has this property that no matter what number you multiply it by you always preserve its sum of digits, but I don't know why only these numbers have this property

Comment: Start with an easier problem. Which two digit numbers don't change digit sum when multiplied by 2?

Comment: How about $111,111,111?$  You need to make a little weaker statement.  Hint: Prove that a number is divisible by 9 if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by 9.

Answer (score 0):

A number is divisible by 9 iff its digit sum is divisible by 9. So any number $n$ not a multiple of 9 will have a different digit sum from $9n$. That leaves us looking at: 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 99.

It is now a question of checking. $27\times7= 189$; $36\times 8=288$; $54\times 7=378$; $63\times 9=567$; $72\times 8=576$; $81\times 6=486$. So all those fail, leaving 18,45,90,99.

Answer: 4.

Answer (score 0):

Every integer, whose digit sum is divisible is divisible by $9$, is divisible by $9$.
However, although multiplying retains divisibility, the digit sums will most often be different.

As advised by @almagest, start by multiplying by $2$ to find the results
$$18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,99$$

Then multiply the above by $9$ to eliminate $54,63,72,81$

Next, use $8$ to eliminate $36$

Then  $7$ to eliminate $27$

This leaves $18,45,90,99$ to be checked against multipliers $3,4,5,6$. There should be no further exclusions.

Your answer is four, which are $18,45,90,99$

Please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: @Ayy Lmao Have I not answered your question, in full detail?